# Gradle JavaFX project with OpenJDK 10

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, openjfx

I have working Gradle/JavaFX project. It worked correctly with JDK8, but now I switched to OpenJDK 10, and my IDE (Eclipse) don't know any JavaFX classes. In maven repositry I found [OpenJFX](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx). I tried to add dependencies to my build.gradle file and rebuild the project, but still there is no JavaFx classes that Eclipse can understand. What is the proper way to add JavaFX dependencies to my project, and why implementing OpenJFX in Gradle didn't help me?

Comment: Have a look at this https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#gradle It is for Java11 but it is time to switch to that anyway.

Comment: Seems it gonna work. I still have some problems with JavaFX modules, but I ask in another question. Thank you for your help.